# How do I position one element under another element using css media queries

Tags: css, positioning, media-queries

I'm stumped. I am creating a basic site. The header has a title and tabs placed side by side. What I would like to do is use css media queries to have the title be above the tabs when the screen gets smaller or on a tablet or iPhone. I used a combination of margins, paddings, float, clear and other css properties but it's not working properly. I was hoping someone out there has solid experience with this and can give me a definitive answer. Thanks. here is a link to [my website](http://www.alexechaparro.com) The styles controlling the titles are as follows.

```
    <div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="tabbedPanels"> <!--Added tabbedPanels to the entire site because each section is a panel-->
                <ul class="tabs" id="Menu"><!--Added class tabs and panel 1, 2, 3, 4-->
                    <li><a href="#panel1" class="normalMenu home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel2" class="normalMenu about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel3" class="normalMenu work">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel4" class="normalMenu contact">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="title">
                    <h1 id="first">Alex</h1>
                    <h1 id="last">Chaparro</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the css

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {    /*and (orientation:portrait) and (max-device-width: 1024px) { /*Added for tab*/
    header{
        height: 150px;
        clear: both
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .title {
        clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: There is no 'definitive answer', however - you should clear floats (float:none), change sizes of elements, and basically - in media queries, you will rewrite most of existing css rules... Check some tutorials...

Comment: I did look at a lot of tutorials and I also rewrote the css elements responsible for these elements but no matter what I did they would crash into each other. I don't know why you voted down this question.

Comment: I didn't voted down (i don't do it, if i don't like question, i just leave page). Please provide your CSS, maybe it could help...

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted... It was a valid question for a Q&A site. That's how sites like these work - someone asks a question, and the community helps out. Upvoted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change order and positioning using only css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376493/change-order-and-positioning-using-only-css)